# How to get the reference class of an subclass object

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am getting into polymorphism but I can't seem to solve this issue. I can't seem to find the correct way of checking whether my object is referenced as the superclass or a subclass. Basically I want to utilize a method to do certain things, depending on the reference class, and NOT the object class. In this example I used "instanceof" in the if condition, but that is wrong of course since both will be listed as Animal...

**Main class:**

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Animal dog1 = new Dog();
        Dog dog2=new Dog();

        List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
        animalList.add(dog1);
        animalList.add(dog2);

        for (Animal animal:animalList) {
            if (animal instanceof Animal){
                animal.talk();
            }
            else if(animal instanceof Dog){
                animal.talk();
                ((Dog)animal).walk();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Animal class:**

```
    public class Animal {
    public void talk(){
    System.out.println("Hello I'm an animal");
    }
  }
```

**Dog class:**

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
public void walk(){
    System.out.println("Dogs can walk");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't. References are checked only compile time, while objects are referred at runtime. So you can only play with Objects. But I don't understand why you need reference? You can't call method of reference, you can only call methods on Objects.

Comment: @GauravJeswani Thank you for your answer. The thing is that I can't use the method "Walk()" for the Animal dog1 = new Dog(); object. So I want a way to check how the object is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every `Dog` walks *every* time it talks, then `Dog` should become:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void talk(){
        super.talk();
        walk();
    }

    public void walk() {
        System.out.println("Dogs can walk");
    }
}
```

and your `main` should then become like:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal dog1 = new Dog();
        Dog dog2 = new Dog();
        Animal plain = new Animal(); //Added a new plain Animal for testing.

        List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
        animalList.add(dog1);
        animalList.add(dog2);
        animalList.add(plain);

        for (final Animal animal: animalList)
            animal.talk();
    }
}
```

As for your code, the problem is than *every* `Animal` reference points to either an `Animal` instance (or any class which extends it), or `null`. You could fix it by changing the order of the `if` conditions like so:

```
for (Animal animal: animalList) {
    if (animal instanceof Dog) {
        animal.talk();
        ((Dog)animal).walk();
    }
    else
        animal.talk();
}
```

which corresponds to:

```
for (Animal animal: animalList) {
    animal.talk();
    if (animal instanceof Dog)
        ((Dog)animal).walk();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
Animal animal1 = new Animal();
Animal animal2 = new Dog();

List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
animalList.add(animal1);
animalList.add(animal2);

for (Animal animal : animalList) {
    animal.talk();
    if(animal instanceof Dog){
        ((Dog)animal).walk();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. This way I can check if an object is of the sub- or superclass, and be sure that I only execute the method of the subclass on the subclass objects ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it can help.
In java you can define the same method with different parameters. Every reference to a dog object will be passed to the `do(Dog dog)` method. Every other animal to `do(Animal animal)`
But this is still based on the object type, not the reference. In your logic all references should be Animal as you are walking through a list of Animal.
Within the for loop there is no link to the dog1 variable anymore.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Animal dog1 = new Dog();
        Dog dog2=new Dog();

        List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
        animalList.add(dog1);
        animalList.add(dog2);

        for (Animal animal:animalList) {
            do(animal);
        }
    }
    public static void do(Animal animal) {
        animal.talk();
    }
    public static void do(Dog dog) {
       dog.talk();
       dog.walk();
    }
}
```